# Can I specialize a variadic template argument based on the signature of its operator()

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a function like this

```
template <typename... FunctionList>
void call_all (int i, float f, const FunctionList... function_list);

template <>
void call_all (int, float)
{
}
```

I want to specialize it something like this:

```
template <typename HasIntArgument, typename... FL>
void call_all (int i, float f, const HasIntArgument & hia, const FL... list)
{
    hia (i);
    call_all (i, f, list...);
}

template <typename HasFloatArgument, typename... FL>
void call_all (int i, float f, const HasFloatArgument & hfa, const FL... list)
{
    hfa (f);
    call_all (i, f, list...);
}
```

In words, I want this function to, for each function-like object in `function_list`, determine whether it is callable with signature `void(int)` or `void(float)`. (Nothing in this list will be callable with more than one signature.)

I want this to work with raw function pointers, lambdas, or anything with a suitable `operator()`.

Can I write a suitable specialization directly, or do I have to do weird stuff with traits classes and SFINAE?

Comment: You cannot partially specialise a function template at all, you want overloading, not specialisation.

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like:

```
#if 0 // C++17
template <typename F>
void dispatch(F func, int i, float f)
{
    if constexpr (has_int_argument<F>::value) {
        func(i);
    } else {
        func(f);
    }
}
#else // C++11
template <typename F>
typename std::enable_if<has_int_argument<F>::value>::type
dispatch(F func, int i, float)
{
    func(i);
}
template <typename F>
typename std::enable_if<!has_int_argument<F>::value>::type
dispatch(F func, int, float f)
{
    func(f);
}
#endif    


template <typename... Fs>
void call_all (int i, float f, const Fs&... fs)
{
    // (dispatch(fs, i, f), ...); // C++17

    const int dummy[] = {0, (dispatch(fs, i, f), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy);
}
```

With appropriate function traits `has_int_argument`. something like:

```
template <typename ClassOrSig> struct funct_trait;

template <typename C>
struct funct_trait : funct_trait<decltype(&C::operator())> {};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct funct_trait<Ret (C::*) (Args...)> : funct_trait<Ret(Args...)> {};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct funct_trait<Ret (C::*) (Args...) const> : funct_trait<Ret(Args...)> {};

// &&, &, volatile, ... (C ellipsis)

template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct funct_trait<Ret (*)(Args...)> : funct_trait<Ret(Args...)> {};

template <typename Ret, typename ...Args>
struct funct_trait<Ret (Args...)>
{
    using sig_type = Ret(Args...);
    using args_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
using has_int_argument = std::is_same<std::tuple<int>,
                                      typename funct_trait<T>::args_tuple>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/833e3e586a078643)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class...Fs>struct overloaded:Fs...{
  using Fs::operator()...;
};
template<class...Fs>
overloaded(Fs...)->overloaded<Fs...>;
```

the above is a bit trickier in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), but implementations exist all over the place.

```
namespace details {
  struct secret_tag {};
  struct secret_result {
    template<class...Ts>
    secret_tag operator()(Ts&&...) const;
  };
  template<class F>
  using secret_tester = overloaded<std::decay_t<F>, secret_result>;
}      
template<class F, class Arg>
using match_arg_exactly = std::integral_constant<
  bool,
  !std::is_same<
    details::secret_tag, 
    std::result_of_t< details::secret_tester<F>(Arg) >
  >{}
>;
```

now we can ask for a given object if it can match a specific argument exactly.

```
template <typename HasIntArgument>
void call_one(int i, float f, std::true_type, const HasIntArgument & hia)
{
  hia (i);
}
template <typename HasFloatArgument>
void call_one(int i, float f, std::false_type, const HasFloatArgument& hia)
{
  hia (f);
}
template <typename F>
void call_one(int i, float f, const F & hia)
{
  call_one( i, f, match_arg_exactly<const F&, int>{}, hia );
}
```

and we use this:

```
void call_all (int, float)
{}

template<class F, class...Fs>
void call_all (int i, float f, F const& f0, Fs const&...fs) {
  call_one( i, f, f0 );
  call_all(i, f, fs...); 
}
```

Test code:

```
struct float_eater {
  void operator()(float x)const{ std::cout<< "float "<<x<<"\n"; }
};
struct int_eater {
  void operator()(int x)const{ std::cout<< "int "<<x<<"\n"; }
};

call_all( 42, 3.14, float_eater{}, int_eater{}, int_eater{} );
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8452ee74eb49c75f)

A [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) `overloaded` is something like:

```
template<class...Fs>
struct overloaded;

template<class F0>
struct overloaded<F0>:F0 {
  overloaded(F0 f0):F0(std::move(f0)) {}
  using F0::operator();
};

template<class F0, class F1>
struct overloaded<F0, F1>: F0, F1 {
  overloaded( F0 f0, F1 f1 ):F0(std::move(f0)), F1(std::move(f1)) {}
  using F0::operator();
  using F1::operator();
};

template<class F0, class...Fs>
struct overloaded<F0, Fs...>:
  overloaded<F0, overloaded<Fs...>>
{
  overloaded(F0 f0, Fs...fs):
    F0(std::move(f0)),
    overloaded<Fs...>( std::move(fs)... )
  {}
};
```

which I think is sufficient for our purposes.  (More generally, you either make a binary tree, balanced or not), and handle perfect forwarding, and... etc.